# Is there a data structure which can insert at an index in O(log n) time?

Tags: data-structures, tree, insert, time-complexity

I'm looking for a data structure with the following properties:

- it contains elements, indexed by a continuous range of numbers (say, from 1 to k), as an array;
- Accessing the element by its index is as fast as possible, hopefully O(1) operation;
- Inserting an element at the given index is O(log n) operation.

I know that insertion operation in heap is O(log n) but I do not see how to use heap here. I would think it is possible to build required data structure based on a tree but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Tree maps is possible since you can traverse the entire Tree at O(log n). This can also include inserting at the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  hash table as you know that the rage is  1,2 .... k index.

So you need to implement a hash function which assign a unique index for every element. or if you have multiple element then you need to take care of hash collision also but hash tables are much better to use according to your question specification .

so accessing will be O(1)
and insertion also O(1) operation